Estimate mousemove value input range wrong
I need to show input range value tooltip at cursor (mouse move). But after click value of input range incorrect as i saw.
Here is my code:


let timeline = document.querySelector('#timeline');
let value = document.querySelector('#value');
let mouse = document.querySelector('#mouse');
timeline.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    value.innerHTML = this.value;
});
timeline.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    mouse.innerHTML = e.offsetX * 100 / e.target.clientWidth;
});
<div style="height: 480px; padding-top: 50px">
    <input type="range" name="timeline" id="timeline" step="0.0001" style="width: 416px">
    <div>Mouse move value: <span id="mouse"></span></div>
    <div>Input range Value: <span id="value"></span></div>
</div>



Run on jsfiddle
Lets me know where is wrong!!
------- Update -------
I was found solution:


let timeline = document.querySelector('#timeline');
let value = document.querySelector('#value');
let mouse = document.querySelector('#mouse');
let moveValue = 0;
timeline.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    value.innerHTML = this.value;
});
timeline.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    moveValue = e.offsetX * 100 / e.target.clientWidth;
    mouse.innerHTML = moveValue;
});
timeline.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
    this.value = moveValue;
});
<div style="height: 480px; padding-top: 50px">
    <input type="range" name="timeline" id="timeline" step="0.0001" style="width: 416px">
    <div>Mouse move value: <span id="mouse"></span></div>
    <div>Input range Value: <span id="value"></span></div>
</div>



Run on jsfiddle

A range slider of width 416px cannot give you the desired precision of step="0.0001" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range

Also, a mousemove might not necessarily trigger at the coordinate necessary to retrieve the Range's value I believe.

Also, the range slider's Thumb radius should be used to scale down the range for the mouse pointer's x position. I.e: when you grag the range slider Thumb to the far left the value is 0 but you can still move one radius distance - therefore you might want to account for two radius when scaling the value

@RokoC.Buljan no... i need mousemoving and click (not drag). I'm developing a timeline of audio player.

drag or not the issues are still the same. You see a value on mousemove, but on click ("change" event) you'll still get another one for the same reasons I mentioned earlier.
